# Publishing Coldfusion Web Service - Returning valid XML (unmarshalling error)

Tags: xml, web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I am trying to publish a web service that allows my client to send me location data (country, state, county, city). I have created a Coldfusion component with a function like this:

```
<cffunction name="LocationRequest" access="remote" returntype="xml" hint="Accepts location">
```

And it returns an XML object. I show the response is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:LOCRequestResult xmlns:ns="http://company.com/">
        <ResponseBody>
            <data_transaction_sequence_num />
            <status>ERROR</status>
            <ResponseType>
                <code>20001</code>
                <message>identity value and/or passkey value is not valid</message>
                <leveltype>ERROR</leveltype>
            </ResponseType>
        </ResponseBody>
    </ns:LOCRequestResult>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My customer is creating a client to consume the web service. He is getting this error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ResponseBody"). Expected elements are <{http://company.com/}ResponseBody>
```

Here is the portion of the WSDL that describes the response:

```
  <xs:element name="LOCRequestResult" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResponseBody" type="ns:responsewrapper" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="responsewrapper">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="data_transaction_sequence_num" type="ns:data_transaction_sequence_num_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Success"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Error"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="SUCCESS"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="ERROR"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ResponseType" type="ns:ResponseTypeType"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ResponseTypeType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="code" nillable="false">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{5,5}"></xs:pattern>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="message">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="2000"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="level" type="ns:levelType" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="levelType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation></xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="INFO"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="WARN"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="ERROR"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="FATAL"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="data_transaction_sequence_num_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,20}"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

How can I change my response XML or WSDL to avoid the unmarshalling error? I cannot exclude the ResponseBody wrapper. I get an error saying the XML is not well formatted if I do. I also tried returning a string (returnformat=plain returntype=string) but it encoded less-than as `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know specifically but here are some things to try.

Use `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes">` and wrap *only* the XML to return in

You may be missing a Header (like "soapenvelope" for example). Soap is finicky.

Use `<cfcontent type="text/XML">` prior to your output.

One of those may be a clue for you. Troubleshooting requests like this is notoriously finicky. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I am hesitant to say this was the answer but I started from scratch and I'm no longer getting the unmarshalling error. The only discernible difference I can see is I have the complexTypes defined BEFORE I reference them as an element attribute "type" in my WSDL.